# how to implement custom tokencleanupservice in identity server4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I kept code in my startup to clean expired tokens like below

```
           opts.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
           opts.TokenCleanupInterval = 3600;
           opts.TokenCleanupBatchSize = 100;
```

But i want to stop delete records when db records get deleted for first batch of 100 or at certain time.

But it continuously deleting records.

So my application getting slow.

Comment: have you tried access the option with IOptions<> and set EnableTokenCleanup to false in your codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own class derived from `TokenCleanupService` and override  the methods you want like `RemoveExpiredPersistedGrantsAsync` or `RemoveConsumedPersistedGrantsAsync`. You can then register it like: `services.AddTransient<ITokenCleanupService, YourTokenCleanupService>();`.